# Using soffice within python, Command works on my Ubuntu server terminal but not work in Python subprocess

Tags: python, libreoffice, pdf

I am having a most major problem with libreoffice in Python

when I run the following in a terminal this works good

```
soffice --headless --convert-to pdf Sample-doc-file-500kb.doc
```

However when I have tried to add this to my python script:

```
subprocess.run(['/usr/bin/soffice', '--headless', '--convert-to',  'pdf', infile, '--outdir', outfile])
```

I get an error:

**/usr/bin/soffice: 46: /usr/bin/soffice: dirname: not found**

I have tried opening up all the permissions of all of the binaries and files and this still doesn't work in the python script. Please tell me What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You did not use a dir in the 1st command so are you sure it is in /usr/bin?  `dirname: not found` seems odd. Is `/usr/bin/soffice` perhaps a directory?

Comment: @Rinzwind `/usr/bin/soffice` is a (link to a) POSIX shell script I think? it should be finding the `/usr/bin/dirname` command from the coreutils package.

Comment: @Rinzwind i see again and again `/usr/bin/soffice` is actual dir of libreoffice where soffice is placed. And i tried without specify dir in python script but this does not work